# Optimize H2 query: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE x=y

Tags: sql, h2

I have a query that looks like this:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
select count(*) from Table t 
where t.outcome='SUCCESS'
```

The 'outcome' column has an index.

H2 tells me  thats its using the index, but I still get something close to a full table scan, because most rows have 'SUCCESS' set, and cardinality is very low.

Is there a way to speed this up? 
Btw., queries without the 'WHERE' part are very fast, just as the doc says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What should work is using 3 subqueries:

```
select
  (select count(*) from table) - 
  (select count(*) from table where outcome<'SUCCESS') -
  (select count(*) from table where outcome>'SUCCESS')
as count
```

This should be fast because the first part is a direct lookup, and the two other queries should be fast (because most `outcome` is usually 'SUCCESS').

If not, could you get the query plan and add it to the question (explain analyze select ...)?

Comment: That worked, thanks! I still don't quite get why equality operator doesn't work, but greater-then / less-then does...

Comment: The equality operator works and uses and index, but as you said the only few entries are not `SUCCESS`, so counting those is faster in this case.