# H2: SELECT DISTINCT slow despite low selectivity

Tags: sql, h2

I am using H2 and have a simple query that looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col
FROM PUBLIC.TABLE;
```

H2 uses a full table scan, even though the selectivity is low, and there is a non-unique index on col.

I checked this and ran:

```
SELECT SELECTIVITY(CLUSTERNODE ) FROM PUBLIC.TRANSFORMATION;
```

Which returned '1'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the index *only* on the desired column, or does it include other columns as well? How many rows are in the table? How recently was the stats table updated? Is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883629 ?

Comment: I didn't know about "analyze", once I executed it, everything was fine, thanks! If you add an answer I will mark it as correct. I just upgraded to the latest version of H2, it seems it will update the table stats automatically, right?  The other question is not solved by that unfortunately.

Comment: You should be able to offer answers to your own questions, and accept them after a certain period - since I don't know exactly what you did to resolve the issue, I think you would be better placed to answer this than I am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why an existing index might not be used by H2 in DISTINCT queries despite low selectivity (=cardinality) is that it maintains table stats internally, which are used to determine column selectivity, and those might be out of date, or not initialized at all.

The docs say that in newer versions, those are updated automatically, but it seems it takes a certain amount of INSERTs (or other mutations), at least in my case an upgrade alone didn't do the trick (I upgraded from 1.2.143 to 1.3.171).

Simply execute an "analyze" update query, and everything should be fine. In my case, execution times dropped from nearly a minute to 300 milliseconds.